# Write-Progress for 10 Minutes PowerShell

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, powershell, powershell-2.0

Hi all is there a way we can show progress bar for 10 minutes with statistics of percentage completed how much time remaining for 10 Minutes? using Write-Progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly the goal is to show some additional
information in the progress messages. This can be done for example by using the
`Activity` parameter. The script below only shows the idea (for 1 minute, for a
shorter test). It should be modified in order to reflect actually needed format
of the message and information to be shown.

```
$time = 60 # seconds, use you actual time in here
foreach($i in (1..$time)) {
    $percentage = $i / $time
    $remaining = New-TimeSpan -Seconds ($time - $i)
    $message = "{0:p0} complete, remaining time {1}" -f $percentage, $remaining
    Write-Progress -Activity $message -PercentComplete ($percentage * 100)
    Start-Sleep 1
}
```

The progress looks like this:

```
57 % complete, remaining time 00:00:26
   Processing
   [oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```