# When does SCCM download updates

Tags: updates, sccm

I'm pretty sure that I know the answer to this but I just want to be sure.

We have SCCM 2012 R2.  Lately I've been receiving complaints from my boss that when deploying updates I am saturating our internet line.

I've configured all the distribution points to not distribute updates during the day via Scheduling and Rate Limits in each distribution point so I can only assume that when I am creating the deployment package for an update that it is then that it is actually downloading the files from Microsoft.  Is this true?

What I need to be able to do is to either proactively or reactively download all updates in off hours ... just occurred to me, is this done through the WUSUS console maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to open the WSUS console, all configuration should be done through the SCCM console. SCCM will configure when and what WSUS will go and check in with Microsoft. In the SCCM console go to /Administration/Site Configuration/Sites/Configure Site Components/Software Update Point. On the 'Sync Schedule' tab you can see when WSUS is scheduled to sync with Microsoft.

Comment: Alright then, I've set the schedule to download updates at 2 AM daily.  Tomorrow I'll check our network monitoring system to see if there is a spike at that time.  I am currently doing a Deploy ... if it's not downloading updates then why does it take so long at the "Provisioning update ..." stage?

Comment: I believe because it has to join all the update information for each update included in the Update Group into the advertisement. All the actually bits are already on the DPs, but the system needs to organize all of what is included in the deployment so that the clients now what is included to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on your collections as to when the clients will go check for missing updates.  You could use a no deadline collection, then use a Powershell script in a Scheduled Task at staggered times to lessen the load.

```
# We start the Software Deployment Evaluation scan and check it initiated successfully.  Below are the TriggerSchedules.
$trigger = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000108}"

$scan = Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName $server -Namespace root\ccm -Class sms_client -Name TriggerSchedule $trigger
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 400
If (Select-String -Path "\\$server\C$\Windows\CCM\Logs\UpdatesDeployment.log" -Pattern 'Message received')
{
$result.scan = "Scan initiaited"
$time = 15 # seconds From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333223/write-progress-for-10-minutes-powershell
foreach($i in (1..$time)) {
 $percentage = $i / $time
 $remaining = New-TimeSpan -Seconds ($time - $i)
 $message = "{0:p0} complete, remaining time {1}" -f $percentage, $remaining
 Write-Progress -Activity "Wait for SCCM scan" -status $message -PercentComplete ($percentage * 100)
 Start-Sleep 1
}#End timer foreach
$result.scan =  "Start SCCM Update Scan"
}#End scan if check
Else{
$result.scan =  "Failed to start SCCM Update Scan"}#End Configuration Manager Software Deployment Evaluation scan.
```

Then you can also install missing updates as a scheduled task.